# How to ignore image resize on zoom in?

Tags: css, responsive-design

How would I go about ignoring to resize image when zooming in on the website just like on this website: http://antares.pcadviser.ro/

My website: http://vizz.tv/

I am using this right now but the image resizes when scrolling in:

```
#headerImage {
    height: 750px; 
    width: 100%;
    background: url(2.jpg) no-repeat;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: auto auto;
    margin-top: -50px;
}
```

I would really appreciate if someone could help me solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
#headerImage {
background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

From [css tricks](http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/). [There's a demo too](http://css-tricks.com/examples/FullPageBackgroundImage/progressive.php)

Comment: [MDN docs for `background-size`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size), which includes a description of the `cover` value (and its opposite, `contain`).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I managed to fix the issue by adding "background-size: cover;". I am however using your example which does the job that I needed it do do, thanks once again.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I managed to fix my issue by adding "background-size: cover;" which apparently auto fills the entire div with my image.

Here is the final code:

```
#headerImage {
    height: 750px; 
    width: 100%;
    background: url(2.jpg) no-repeat;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    margin-top: -50px;
}
```